# get size of each row in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

Hi I'm new in Qt programming and I want to know how to get the size of each row in QTextEdit.

**Update**:
I need to get the width of each row (line) in the text, and not the width of all text in a QTextEdit.

Comment: Do you mean size in characters? Pixels? PS: don't apologize for your English.

Comment: QTextEdit, or rather the QTextDocument shown by QTextEdit, does not really have rows, it has blocks. So yeah, please clarify the question, what kind of size of what exactly, and for what purpose, do you want?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

If you want get size (wide and high) of your text in pixels & length of every string in `QTextEdit`,  you can do:

```
// split all text into list of strings by separator '\n' (new line symbol)
QStringList strLst = ui->textEdit->toPlainText().split('\n');
// gather font metrics in QTextEdit
QFont textEditFont = ui->textEdit->font();
QFontMetrics fm(textEditFont);
foreach (QString str, strLst)
{
    int pixelsWide = fm.width(str);
    int pixelsHigh = fm.height();
    qDebug() << QString("Row: %1:\n\tsymbols count = %2,\tpixels wide = %3,"
             "\tpixels high = %4")
                .arg(str)
                .arg(str.length())
                .arg(pixelsWide)
                .arg(pixelsHigh);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. So in fact I need to get the width of each row (line) in the text, and not the width of all text in a QTextEdit.
Thanks for the help, and sorry again.
Regards.

Comment: What kind of value want you get -- count of symbols, count of pixels (as above)?

Comment: Try to split all your text into strings by symbol '\n' and count length of each string.